# What does the ">" symbol mean in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain what the `>` symbol does in [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469(v=vs.85).aspx) scripting?

To be specific, I am looking at the following line:

```
New-Item $env:Passwords -ItemType Directory -Force > $null  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the redirection operator, specifically for output. In this case, it redirects (sends) the output of `New-Item` to the destination `$null` - IOW, it suppresses it so there is no output.

You can see the help topic `about_Redirection`, or for more general information [Using command redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: You could also direct the OP to `help about_Redirection`

Comment: That helps. While we are at the topic, could you please tell me what does,"%" symbol after the pipeline means and the meaning of "$_" symbol. I am having  trouble finding these on the documentation.         Sort-Object Name |% ` and  $issue = $_

Comment: See `help %` and `help About_automatic_Variables`.

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks. I was looking at MSDN for a more generic link, but I've added the topic you mention as well.